# Dynamic host-based mount on Wicket

Tags: wicket

I have an unusual requirement for Wicket. I chose Wicket because I will make my website design-centric and it's URL-mounting features are simply the best for SEO. Unfortunatelly, I found a bump.

I want to create a site with different designs for different hosts. This site will have some host aliases (let's say: "abc.com", "abc.com.br", "abc.com.pl") - all pointing to the same codebase (i.e. the same tomcat host instance). That part is already up and running, thanks to Tomcat and a custom ResourceStreamLocator.

Now, I want different mounts for different hosts. This means "abc.com/page1", "abc.com.br/pagina1" and "abc.com.pl/strona1" must point to the same "Page1.class" page. Users from "abc.com" cannot see "abc.com/pagina1" or "abc.com/strona1".

How can I do this "dynamic host-based mount"?

Please notice I'm NOT talking about i18n. I'm using this example because it's simple to explan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your solution give you multiple webapp instances backed by the same codebase though? If it is, I don't think there's anything you should do.

I don't know if there's an out-of-the-box solution to do this from within a single webapp, but if there isn't, this is what I'd do.

The first thing is that for this to work seamlessly you'll need separate application instances.

How to achieve this?

Extend the `WicketFilter` class (this is the servlet filter that links the servlet container to Wicket). This class has a field called `webApplication`, which you'll have to replace with a vhostname-application map. (This also means copying the entire code of the `doFilter()` method, so it's not a very neat solution. It's more of a hack. Anyway)

This should do the trick, you'll have one separate application instance per vhost.

But your session variables will still be shared between the sites, which is a bad idea. (In practice your browser won't send cookies issued by one vhost to another vhost, but if the session id is put in the url, you can cross vhosts this way.)

To avoid sessions getting mixed up, you'll have to change the `getFilterConfig()` method too, so that it returns a different config to different application instances. (Filter name is the attribute that is used for session variable prefixing.)

I'm not 100% sure this will work, I haven't tried it but if you can't find a better (and more importantly, cleaner) solution, this is your only option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I'm using a single webapp to keep deployment simple. Unfortunatelly, I saw WicketFilter is not well-designed for extension - "webApplication" is private and used without a getter. To use your solution, I have to reimplement all of the filter... :( But you gave me some new ideas to explore! Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I did it! Instead of extending WicketFilter, I implemented Filter with a vhost map, isolating application instances as you said. This also solves the session problem, because I can pass a new FilterConfig when initing WicketFilter.

Comment: Nice one, I should've thought about chaining the filters.

Comment: @ireddick This was my first (and successful) attempt: http://pastebin.com/dhqNtHiY

Comment: That's really neat. Definitely a lot better than my idea. :)

Comment: Thanks! But you deserve the credits, because you pointed me the solution was "separate application instances". I was lost trying to customize the URL mounting!

Answer (score 2):

This requirement is quite easy in Wicket 1.5.
You just need to setup custom root request mapper which will receive the request before all predefined (system) request mappers. This way you can check the request url and return the respective page or let the default mappers process the url if it doesn't match any of your mappings.

See Application#setRootRequestMapper() and IRequestMapper interface. HttpsMapper and CryptoMapper work this way.

Another way to do the same is to #mount(IRequestMapper) with very high IRequestMapper#getCompatibilityScore). This score is used by Wicket to decide which mapper to use with the default root mapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think it solves the session problem as pointed by biziclop, but I will give +1 because it seems simple to use.

Comment: I didn't read his complete answer... See my response in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599892/how-can-i-reuse-code-when-two-different-wicket-applications-share-common-function . Using this approach you'll have several .war which reuse the same .jar. The .jar will contain the common components, behaviors, ... The .wars will have their specific Application classes which may extend from your BaseApplication class and they will do just the mounting.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but my problem was different. Something like a "css zen garden" where the HTML and URL mounting changes, too. But thanks anyway! I know I will need to use that someday! :)